# В каких случаях показывать функцию предопределенным процессом?

Tags: алгоритм, блок-схема

Сейчас разбираюсь с блок-схемами и у меня появился вопрос, который я не знаю как гуглить, поэтому излагаю суть:
В блок-схемах есть отдельный [блок](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Flowchart_preprocess.png?uselang=ru) для предопределенных процессов, в котором стОит писать, что мы вызываем функцию. Но, на сколько я понимаю, по-хорошему весь код программы должен состоять из набора функций - например, если нам нужно посчитать сумму чисел в столбиках и линиях массива массивов (матрица получается), то должна быть

- функция, считающая сумму в столбцах
- функция, считающая сумму по линиям
- функция, которая вызовет две предыдущие и выведет результат на экран

в таком случае вся моя блок-схема должна состоять из вышеуказанных блоков, или их нужно использовать для более больших функций? когда вообще использовать предопределенный процесс, а когда писать действие просто в блоке действия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можете использовать как в рисунке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с правой стороне как начало указано название функции и параметры